# Fetch string from file in python

Tags: python, string

I have a text file from which I want to extract a certain string based on a variable `site` which represents the location of some character. I want to extract 20 characters before and after the location of `site`.
My code works perfectly well if the value of `site` is over 20. But if it has less than 20 characters before `site`, it doesn't return anything.

For example, I have a string here where `site=5` which in this case is `K`.

```
MSGRGKGGKGLGKGGAKRHRKVLRDXYZX
```

Now I am trying to extract 20 characters before and after the character `K`.
Below is my code;

```
data=myfile.read()    
str1 = data[site:site+1+20]
temp = data[site-20:site]
final_sequence = temp+str1
print final_sequence
```

This gives me an output of `KGGKGLGKGGAKRHRKVLRDX`. Since it couldn't find 20 characters before `K`, it didn't print the chaarcters before `K`.

The correct should have been `MSGRGKGGKGLGKGGAKRHRKVLRDX`.

Which brings me to my question. How can I modify my code to print all characters before `K` if there are less than 20 characters downstream of the value of `K`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that since `site-20` is negative Python considers it an index relative to the end of the sequence, and so the slice is empty (because the first index is posterior to the last index). Just make sure you never go below 0.

```
data=myfile.read()    
str1 = data[site:site+1+20]
temp = data[max(site-20, 0):site]
final_sequence = temp+str1
print final_sequence
```

Or shorter

```
data=myfile.read()    
final_sequence = data[max(site-20, 0):site+1+20]
print final_sequence
```

Note that you do not need to use `min(site+1+20, len(data))` for the upper bound because Python automatically clips slice indices beyond the end of the sequence to the sequence length.

Comment: Noted. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check upper bound and lower bound of the length of your file. Because negative value (for before location) must be checked and same rule for the upper bound (for after location).

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is also right using MAX. 
Following example is non pythonic way using condition.

```
data = "MSGRGKGGKGLGKGGAKRHRKVLRDXYZX"

str1 = data[site:site+1+20]
if site <= 20:
     temp = data[0:site]
elif site > 20:
    temp = data[site%20:site]

print str1 + temp
```

Write proper unittest case with different data to verify your logic.